# How to run events in global.asax.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, code-behind, global-asax

I use Visual Studio 2019 to create a new webforms project. I write a `Session_Start` event in the `Global.asax.cs`, but it never fires!

Here is some code - `Global.asax`

```
<%@ Application CodeBehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="webApp.Global" Language="C#" %>
```

`Global.asax.cs`:

```
namespace webApp
{
    public class Global : HttpApplication
    {
        void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Code that runs on application startup
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            Application["test"] = "123";
        }

        void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Session["test"] = "123";
        }
    }
}
```

Default.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string test = Application["test"].ToString();
    string test1 = Session["test"].ToString();
}
```

When the program runs into the `Page_Load` of `Default.aspx.cs`, it will throw an exception: `System.NullReferenceException`

What can I do?

Comment: I am not totally familiar with webforms. but it seems to me you need to declare Application and Session as something before using them?

Comment: Is your file actually Globa.asax? It should be Global.asax. And I always fully support Dai's statements - there's no good reason to be starting a new Web Forms project. Just don't. There's so many easier to use, faster, and better supported platforms like ASP.NET Core MVC, Razor Pages, Blazor, ASP.NET Core Web API w/ a JavaScript front end etc.

Comment: Which of the two lines in your `Page_Load` handler does it throw the exception on? Can it read the `Application["test"]` value? Have you **configured** session (in your `web.config`) ?